add date columns
I have two columns with date and I need to create another based on sum of those two. df looks like below:
date_1                         date_2                    result_date
2024-07-07 18:00:00.000000     0001-01-02T01:12:53.832   2024-07-08 19:12:53
2024-07-07 08:46:00.000000     0001-01-04T08:00:00       2024-07-10 16:46:00
2024-07-07 17:42:00.000000     0001-01-08T02:00:00       2024-07-14 19:42:00
2024-07-07 17:42:00.000000     0002-01-01T02:00:00       2025-07-07 19:42:00

The type of date_1 and date_2 columns are "object". In date_2 column, the code shows date from year one. I am not sure how I could add them.
data = {
    'date_1': ['2024-07-07 18:00:00.000000', '2024-07-07 08:46:00.000000', '2024-07-07 17:42:00.000000', '2024-07-07 17:42:00.000000'],
    'date_2': ['0001-01-02T01:12:53.832', '0001-01-04T08:00:00', '0001-01-08T02:00:00', '0002-01-01T02:00:00']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


Don't put a solution in the question. You can post it as an answer instead. (Yes, you can answer your own question.) Think of it like, the question is about the problem and each answer is about a solution.

Valid pandas timestamps are between years 1677 and 2262:
pd.Timestamp.min
# Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145224193')

pd.Timestamp.max
# Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')

Thus you cannot directly convert date_2 to datetime. What you could do is to first replace the year to add 1678, then convert to_datetime, subtract the reference year (1678) to convert to timedelta and add it to date_1:
ref_year = 1678

date_2 = (df['date_2']
          .str.replace('^(\d{4})',
                       lambda m: str(ref_year-1+int(m.group(0))),
                       regex=True)
          .pipe(pd.to_datetime, format='mixed')
         )

df['result_date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['date_1'])
                       .add(date_2.sub(pd.Timestamp(year=ref, month=1, day=1)))
                    )

Output:
                       date_1                   date_2             result_date
0  2024-07-07 18:00:00.000000  0001-01-02T01:12:53.832 2024-07-08 19:12:53.832
1  2024-07-07 08:46:00.000000      0001-01-04T08:00:00 2024-07-10 16:46:00.000
2  2024-07-07 17:42:00.000000      0001-01-08T02:00:00 2024-07-14 19:42:00.000
3  2024-07-07 17:42:00.000000      0002-01-01T02:00:00 2025-07-07 19:42:00.000

Using date_1's year as reference
Using a fixed year as reference could be problematic because of leap years and other non-fixed time variations. Another option could be to consider the year of date_1 as reference
year1 = df['date_1'].str.extract('^(\d+)', expand=False)
year2 = df['date_2'].str.extract('^(\d+)', expand=False)
ref_year = (pd.to_numeric(year1)+pd.to_numeric(year2)-1).astype(str)

df['result_date'] = (
 pd.to_datetime(ref_year+df['date_2'].str[4:], format='mixed')
   .sub(pd.to_datetime(year1, format='%Y'))
   .add(pd.to_datetime(df['date_1']))
)

Here we see a slightly different output, now the last result_date is 2025-07-08 because 2024 is a leap year. Of course the exact logic could be adapted to the exact use case.
Output:
                       date_1                   date_2             result_date
0  2024-07-07 18:00:00.000000  0001-01-02T01:12:53.832 2026-07-08 19:12:53.832
1  2024-07-07 08:46:00.000000      0001-01-04T08:00:00 2026-07-10 16:46:00.000
2  2024-07-07 17:42:00.000000      0001-01-08T02:00:00 2026-07-14 19:42:00.000
3  2024-07-07 17:42:00.000000      0002-01-01T02:00:00 2027-07-08 19:42:00.000

Using non-vectorized Date Offset
The last option could be to split date_2 in Year/Month/Day/Time and to apply a DateOffset for each type:
Y = tmp[0].astype(int).sub(1)*pd.DateOffset(years=1)
M = tmp[1].astype(int).sub(1)*pd.DateOffset(months=1)
D = tmp[2].astype(int).sub(1)*pd.DateOffset(days=1)
T = pd.to_timedelta(tmp[3])
df['result_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_1'])+Y+M+D+T

Or:
tmp = df['date_2'].str.extract('(?P<years>\d{4})-(?P<months>\d{2})-(?P<days>\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:.\d*)?)')

df['result_date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['date_1'])
                     .add(pd.to_timedelta(tmp[3]))
                     .add(tmp.iloc[:, :3].astype(int).sub(1)
                             .agg(lambda x: pd.DateOffset(**dict(x)), axis=1))
                    )

Output:
                       date_1                   date_2                 result_date
0  2024-07-07 18:00:00.000000  0001-01-02T01:12:53.832  2024-07-08 19:12:53.832000
1  2024-07-07 08:46:00.000000      0001-01-04T08:00:00         2024-07-10 16:46:00
2  2024-07-07 17:42:00.000000      0001-01-08T02:00:00         2024-07-14 19:42:00
3  2024-07-07 17:42:00.000000      0002-01-01T02:00:00         2025-07-07 19:42:00


The idea of using a timedelta by using ref year is great. so +1. However, timedelta can't represent a full year exactly, which causes the 366-day issue. If you replace 2024 with 2023 in the example, you'll see 366-day issues.

@PandaKim that's a very good point but that's intrinsic to OP's logic/format, if you pick the reference to be a specific reference for this format instead of 1678 that should be fine. Otherwise, there is unfortunately an ambiguity that is impossible to solve without extra rules.

I've added two extra options that should cover most use cases

You need to convert date_1 column to datetime:
df["date_1"] = df["date_1"].apply(pd.to_datetime)
Then convert date_2 to timedelta:
df["date_2"] = df["date_2"].apply(pd.to_timedelta)
And finally add them up:
df["result_date"] = df["date_1"] + df["date_2"]
This is off the top of my head and might have some errors but should be pretty close.

When I try to conver date_t to timedelta i got error: OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 01:12:53 present at position 0. I try to use: , df["date_2"] = df["date_2"].apply(pd.to_timedelta, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') but it didn't help

Oh I see. I think you need to convert date_2 to datetime, then substract 01-01-0001 12:00:00 (Jan 1st 0001 ) to get the correct timedelta.
